# How many neurons should I use in my AI otput layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am making AI that will recognise price from url. I found best arcitecture for it but still have last question: How many neurons should I use in last output layer? The otput should look like: "1100usd, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't need a dollar sign to be a part of the neural network's prediction, so you are looking for it to output a single value. Therefore, your output layer would be a dense layer with a single neuron.

Comment: but if it wil be like 1100USD?

Comment: Well the model should output 1100, just the number. If you'd like, you can write a function that will call the model and print the output concatenated with a dollar sign or "USD"

`output = model.predict(input)` then 

`print(str(output) + "USD")`